# How do I find poles and zeros from an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, roots, control-theory

Assume that you having an ODE.

$$\dot x = x^3y x^2 + x + y + 10$$

How can I find the poles and zeroes here?

If I was using a transfer function,

$$G(s) = \frac{s^2 + 1}{s^2 + 0.1s + 50}$$

then the poles would be the roots of $0 = s^2 + 0.1s + 50$ and the zeros would be the roots of $0 = s^2 + 1$

But in this case, I don't have a transfer function. Just a regular ODE.

Comment: In your ODE, which is the independent variable?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Independent? Well, You can assume the $y$ is the "input signal" and $x$ is the "output signal".

Comment: Does the first term on the right, $x^3yx^2$, have some special meaning or could it be combined to $x^5y$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I just made up something. You can say $x^5y$.

Comment: The transfer function applies to a linear DE, linear on both sides, input and output, $$\ddot x+0.1\dot x+50x=\ddot y+y.$$

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry, I don't understand. Is that ODE the same as above?

Comment: Yes, that was to highlight that your second example is linear, while the original is highly non-linear. You are comparing falling or rising amplitudes with explosive divergence at finite time, that is, qualitatively different phenomena.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I don't understand this either. Is it not possible to find the roots of my ODE? Find the poles and zeros...not possible?

Comment: Your ODE is nonlinear. So, there is no transfer function associated with it and, therefore, no poles and zeros (even though the concept of zeros can be extended to the nonlinear case but this is way beyond this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poles and zeros are a concept that is defined for transfer functions. Transfer functions are a concept that is defined for linear, time invariant systems.

Your system however is nonlinear, so the concept of poles/zeros is not defined for such systems; so it doesn't make sense to ask for the poles/zeros of such a system.

You can however linearize the system, as that gives you a linear system which has poles and zeros that you can analyze. Since you say the $y$ is an input and $x$ an output I redefine the input to $u$ and the output to $y$ which is more standard:

\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=x+10+x^5u+u\\
y&=x
\end{align}

First note that this system does not have a unique equilibrium. So for linearization, you have to choose which equilibrium point you want to analyze. For example, say you are interested in the equilibrium $x=0,u=-10$. The linearization matrices are:

$$
\begin{align}
A&=5 u x^4 + 1\\
B&=x^5 + 1\\
C&=1\\
D&=0
\end{align}
$$

So at $x=0,u=-10$ you get:

$$
\begin{align}
A&=1\\
B&=1\\
C&=1\\
D&=0
\end{align}
$$

This can be used to compute the transfer function

$$
G(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B+D
$$

($I$ is the identity matrix). So if you plug everything in you get

$$
G(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}
$$

So at the equilibrium $x=0,u=-10$, the linearized system of your nonlinear system has no zeros and one pole at $s=1$. Since the pole has positive real part, this equilibrium is unstable.

Of course, the linearization is an approximation that is only valid in a neighborhood of the equilibrium point. At other equilibrium points the system might have a very different behaviour.

Comment: As said in a comment, zeros exist for nonlinear systems. This is due to seminal works by Isidori and others.

Comment: @KBS Not really, what you mean is zero dynamics. But this is not the same as the zeros of a transfer function. A nonlinear system doesn't have zeros.

Comment: Zero dynamics for nonlinear systems are the same as the zero dynamics for linear systems, which are given by the zeros of the transfer function. This follows from the definition. But one cannot necessarily assign numbers to those zeros, but the concept is there (except in some special cases where the zero dynamics is linear).

Comment: @KBS Correct, zero dynamics is the generalization. However, "zeros exist for nonlinear systems" is (strictly speaking) incorrect, because "zeros" is the special case applicable to linear (time-invariant) systems only.

Comment: Yes, that was badly formulated on my side. What I wanted to say is that the concept is not restricted to linear systems only.

Comment: So you step 1: Linearize the system. Step 2: Turn it into a state space model. Step 3: Check the poles and zeros of $A$ matrix. Ok. That's a good answer.